# Ueditor can not display properly in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    var options = {
        toolbars: [
            ['fullscreen', 'source', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'fontborder', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'removeformat', 'formatmatch', 'autotypeset', 'blockquote', 'pasteplain', '|', 'forecolor', 'backcolor', 'insertorderedlist', 'insertunorderedlist', 'selectall', 'cleardoc', '|', 'rowspacingtop', 'rowspacingbottom', 'lineheight', '|', 'customstyle', 'paragraph', 'fontfamily', 'fontsize', '|', 'directionalityltr', 'directionalityrtl', 'indent', '|', 'justifyleft', 'justifycenter', 'justifyright', 'justifyjustify', '|', 'touppercase', 'tolowercase', '|', 'link', 'unlink', 'anchor', '|', 'imagenone', 'imageleft', 'imageright', 'imagecenter', '|', 'insertimage', 'emotion', 'scrawl', 'attachment', 'map', 'gmap', 'insertcode', 'pagebreak', '|', 'horizontal', 'date', 'time', 'spechars', 'wordimage', '|', 'inserttable', 'deletetable', 'insertparagraphbeforetable', 'insertrow', 'deleterow', 'insertcol', 'deletecol', 'mergecells', 'mergeright', 'mergedown', 'splittocells', 'splittorows', 'splittocols', '|', 'print', 'preview', 'searchreplace', 'help']
        ],
        lang: /^zh/.test(navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.userLanguage) ? 'zh-cn' : 'en',
        langPath: UEDITOR_HOME_URL + "lang/",

        webAppKey: "9HrmGf2ul4mlyK8ktO2Ziayd",
        initialFrameHeight: 420,
        focus: true,
        autoHeightEnabled: false
    };
    var ue = UE.getEditor('editor_solve', options);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    var ue = UE.getEditor('editor_code', options);
    var ue = UE.getEditor('editor_tran', options);
</script>
```

the result show in IE is that

[image]

the last ueditor displays properly,but the first and second one could not.
The problem only exists in IE browser. It works well in chrome and firefox.

Thanks, Any help Plz.